# How to update json in s3 using python boto3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

Iam trying to update the json file which resides in the s3 bucket. I gone thorough different approach, but nothing seems working.

Below is the code

```
import boto3
import json

#Loading Json from s3
s3= boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='id',aws_secret_access_key='key')
obj=s3.Object('s3python','test.json')
body=obj.get()['Body'].read()
jsonContent=json.loads(body)
print(jsonContent)
```

I am getting following error

```
Error
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Udpate new value once if the json reading is successful below

```
updateJson={}
for k,v in jsonContent.items():
    updateJson[k]=v

updateJson['key']='newvalue'


json_dump_s3 = lambda obj, f: s3.Object(key=f).put(Body=json.dumps(obj))

key='test.json'
json_dump_s3(updateJson,key)
#Writing Json to s3
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: what is the form of test.json?

Comment: HI @hjpotter, here is the json file content
{"PediID": "yellow", "DediID": "green","ediIDTime":"12", 
"PleaID": "green", "DleapamersID": "yellow","leaIDTime":"23", 
"PleaID": "yellow", "DleaID": "green","leaID":"45"}

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing the solution as it might help others who are facing the same error.

The error is due to missing decode(). So just need to replace below line :

```
body=obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

Updated :

```
body=obj.get()['Body'].read().decode()
```